# Coefficients of minimal polynomial are polynomials of the conjugates

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

In Atiyah-MacDonald's *Commutative Algebra*, proof of Proposition 5.15, the authors claim that the coefficients of the minimal polynomial of an element $x$ over a field $K$, say $\text{Irr}(x, K)=X^n + a_{n - 1} X^{n - 1} + ... + a_1 X + a_0$, are polynomials of the conjugates $x_1, ..., x_n$ of $x$. I do not quite see why this should be the case.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjugates of $x$ are the roots of $\text{Irr}(x,K)$, and therefore the coefficients of the minimal polynomial are $s_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, where $s_i$ is the $i$th symmetric polynomial. See [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).